# Buenas tardes, si me pueden colaborar para modificar este código para que el método pase de O(n^2) a O(n)

Tags: java

Debo modificar la implementación del método remove_all para optimizar el código de  O(n^2) a O(n), ya he tratado de reducirlo pero no me ha dado resultado, si me pueden ayudar estaré muy muy agradecido..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class DoublyLinkedList<T> implements List<T> {

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int size;
    
    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        size = 0;
    }
    
    public void add(T x, int pos) throws Exception {
        if (pos<0 || pos>size)
            throw new Exception("Index out of bounds - pos:" + pos + " size:" + size);
        if (size==0) {
            Node new_node = new Node(x);
            head = new_node;
            tail = new_node;
            size++;
        }
        else if (pos == 0) {
            Node new_node = new Node(x);
            new_node.next = head;
            head.prev = new_node;
            head = new_node;
            size++;
        }
        else if (pos==size) {
            Node new_node = new Node(x);
            tail.next = new_node;
            new_node.prev = tail;
            tail = new_node;            
            size++;
        }
        else {
            Node p = head;
            for (int i = 0; i < pos-1; i++)
                p = p.next;
            Node q = p.next;
            Node new_node = new Node(x);
            new_node.next = q;
            p.next = new_node;
            new_node.prev = p;
            q.prev = new_node;
            size++;
        }
    }
    
    public void remove_pos(int pos) throws Exception {
        if (pos<0 || pos>=size)
            throw new Exception("Index out of bounds - pos:" + pos + " size:" + size);
        if (size==1) {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
            size = 0;
        }
        else if (pos==0) {
            head = head.next;
            head.prev = null;
            size--;
        }
        else if (pos==size-1) {
            tail = tail.prev;
            tail.next = null;
            size--;
        }
        else {
            Node p = head;
            for (int i = 0; i < pos-1; i++)
                p = p.next;
            Node q = p.next.next;
            p.next = q;
            q.prev = p;
            size--;
        }
    }
    
    public T get(int pos) throws Exception {
        if (pos<0 || pos>=size)
            throw new Exception("Index out of bounds - pos:" + pos + " size:" + size);
        if (pos == size-1)
            return tail.data;
        Node p = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
            p = p.next;
        return p.data;
    }

    public void set(T x, int pos) throws Exception {
        if (pos<0 || pos>=size)
            throw new Exception("Index out of bounds - pos:" + pos + " size:" + size);
        if (pos == size-1)
            tail.data = x;
        Node p = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
            p = p.next;
        p.data = x;
    }
    
    public int find(T x) {
        Node p = head;
        int i = 0;
        while (p!=null) {
            if (p.data.equals(x)) return i;
            p = p.next;
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    
    public void remove_val(T x) {
        int pos = find(x);
        if (pos==-1) return;
        try {
            remove_pos(pos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    
    //O(n^2) - Es posible hacerlo O(n)
    public void remove_all(T x) {
        int pos = find(x);
        while (pos!=-1) {
            try {
                remove_pos(pos);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            pos = find(x);          
        }
    }

    public int get_size() {
        return size;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        String s = "[";
        Node p = head;
        while(p!=null) {
            s += p.data + ",";
            p = p.next;
        }
        s += "]";
        return s;
    }

    private class Node {
        T data;
        Node next;
        Node prev;
        Node (T data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
            this.prev = null;
        }
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new ListIterator();
    }
    
    private class ListIterator implements Iterator<T> {

        private Node p;
        
        ListIterator() {
            this.p = head;
        
        }
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return p!=null;
        }

        public T next() {
            if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            else {
                T x = p.data;
                p = p.next;
                return x;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no dupliques las preguntas (ya tienes [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/392060/ayuda-para-poder-modificar-la-implementaci%C3%B3n-de-%C3%A9ste-m%C3%A9todo-para-que-su-compleji) que es exactamente la misma). He votado para cerrarla por este motivo.

Comment: @E.Betanzos No bro, es que son códigos distintos

Comment: Si miras en el [historial de ediciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/392060/revisions), solicitaste ayuda por el método `void remove_all(T x)`, lo mismo que haces aquí.

Comment: @E.Betanzos pero al ser distinto el código puede que la solucion sea distinta creo yo

Comment: Si vas a eliminar todo el contenido del objeto, simplemente reinicializalo. Es mejor que O(n) ... es O(1), o sea, costo constante.